# sort the output file after the Reduce

Tags: mapreduce

I'm using mapreduce to count words for example, and I want the output file will be sorted by the occurrences of the words. for example:

```
one two two three three three four four four four
```

the output will be:

```
four 4
three 3
two 2
one 1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Some programming languages can work with ordered dictionaries, and doing a mapreduce on such structure will keep the order of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that is by adding an extra map-reduce step that does a "[Secondary Sort](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=hadoop%20Secondary%20Sort)".

1. The map simply creates the key that is used to do the sorting.
2. The shuffle/sort phase then does the sorting.
3. The reducer simply outputs the sorted result.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to:

1. Sort each individual reducer output the way you want to. So, for example, if you were using Streaming and Python to run your job, with Hadoop 0.21.0 you could specify this as your reducer: `-reducer "myReducer.py | sort -k 2 -r"`.
2. Merge-sort all reducer output files when your job is done. Since the reducer outputs are all sorted you are essentially just merging. So, for example, after you copy all files from HDFS locally (`hadoop dfs -get myWordCountResults/part* ./results/`) you can run `sort -m ./results/part* > sortedOutput.txt`

Comment: According to this [link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/streaming.html#Can+I+use+UNIX+pipes%3F) UNIX pipes don't work with reducer/mapper arguments.  This is link outdated?